Google Sheets - Tocol or how to mimic a pivot table?
I am wondering if this is possible - here is the raw data format, which comes from an online form:



Parent Name
Child 1
Child 2
Child 3




Bob
Steve
John
Cody



Here is what I would like it to do (Live a pivot table):



Parent
Child




Bob
Steve


Bob
John


Bob
Cody



I would like to populate the parent name to match the row of which the child is associated to. The closest thing to work is a lookup, but lookups only search for the first column in the range, so they kick errors for child 2 and 3.
Pivot tables work, but unfortunately I can't use a pivot for this workbook.
I'm guessing it's possible using "query" but do not know which statement would achieve this.
Thanks!
Here is where I am currently at:



Parent
Child (Tocol formula)





Steve



John



Cody




Another solution:
=REDUCE({"Parent","Child"},TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(a,p,
   {a;IFNA(HSTACK(p,TOCOL(XLOOKUP(p,A2:A,B2:D),1)),p)}))




Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1),reduce(Σ,B2:D,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(c="",Σ,{index(A:A,row(c)),c})))))


Alternative:
=query(arrayformula(split(tocol(A2:A&"|"&B2:D,1),"|")),"where Col2<>''")


try:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(IF((A2:A="")+(B2:D="");;A2:A&"×"&B2:D); 1); "×"))


